# TVöD pay scale for 1st year PhD in Bayern

Tags: phd, germany, salary

In my contract, it says salary is according to "TVöD level 13". Can anyone tell me which table belongs to this category from all the tables in öffentlicher-dienst.info. There are many TVöD tables and I don't know which one is mine.

My tax class is 1 and working hours is full time and position is in Bayern.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tvoed/bund?id=tvoed-bund-2019&matrix=1) is the table.

You have to look at row E13, which is the standard monthly pay for PhD students with a full position in Germany. The first column is for the first year, then you advance to the second column at the beginning of the second year, and to the third column at the beginning of the fourth year.

Those are values before taxes. Clicking on the number leads you to an online calculator that estimates the value after taxes.

This amount is paid 12.5 times a year: one salary per month plus an additional half salary in November as Christmas money (Weihnachtsgeld/Sonderzahlung).

The above is valid for doctoral students with full positions, which are common in engineering. It is common in many other fields to have partial positions (50% or 65% of a position). In this case, the contract will specify a reduced number of hours per week (20.05 or 26.65 instead of 40.1 hours per week in Bayern) and the corresponding percentage will be applied to the salary before taxes. The percentage after taxes will be higher due to a reduced tax rate: there are online calculators such as [this one](https://www.brutto-netto-rechner.info/) that estimate this value.

Comment: But I believe that graduate students typically have 50% positions -- so only half of the full-time salary.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth That depends on the field, institution and funding agency. 50% positions have become rare. Nowadays phd positions in the sciences are mostly 65%, in engineering 100%.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth there are full positions for PhD students, especially in engineering. OP explicitly said they have a full position.

Comment: It is worth noting that the monthly salary is indeed payed 12 times per year (i.e. including the summer break) unlike the 9-month salaries sometimes payed at US universities.

Comment: @MKR actually, 12.5 times, because there is an extra half salary in November as Christmas money. I added all this to the answer (partial positions and extra salary).

Comment: @wimi -- damn! I was in the wrong field then when I got my PhD in Germany. A full time graduate student salary ain't so bad, apparently!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth it isn't... No wonder that doctoral studies often take 5 years... If the student is good and the position is full, neither the student nor the professor are in a hurry to finish!

Comment: @wimi thank you for the well written answer. PhD student also gets Weihnachtsgeld during 6 month probation ?? I mean if November falls in the 6-month period ? There are usually some differences between employees in probation period and post- probation period, atleast in Industries. Is there such thing for PhD students as well?

Comment: @karthick on your first year, you will get the proportional part of the Weihnachtsgeld according to how many months you have worked until the end of November. For example, if you start on 1st October, at the end of November you will have worked 2 months, so you will get 2/12 of the standard half salary as Weihnachtsgeld.